# Autoreleasepool error ARC

Tags: swift, macos, automatic-ref-counting

I am developing an osx app in swift language. I am facing an error related to auto release pool and I can't able to trigger out.
Here I am attaching the error what I am getting from console. I am new to OSX app development and can you please suggest any methods or reference to trigger outing this kind of errors.
Following are the details about the development environment
Xcode Version 7.1
Swift version 2.1
Osx version 10.10.5

[image]

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Are you working with `CoreFoundation` functions? Or are you using `unowned` properties?

Comment: You have a heap corruption issue. Use the address sanitizer. [Watch this video from WWDC 2015](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-413) for instructions.

Comment: I am using NSStream, for tcp connection

Comment: Not using unowned keyword